# How do I make PDF files to be opened as a Google Chrome application?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extensions, file-association

I want to use Google Chrome browser as my default PDF reader so I've associated .pdf file extension with the Google Chrome. But I'd also like Chrome to open it as an application window. I know I can make an application shortcut using the following:

```
chrome.exe --app="some/url"
```

But I don't want to create a separate shortcut for each .pdf file I have. Is there way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

So You mean simply how to set a default program?

Right click on a PDF file, Open with... and Set default program. You select chrome, or if You don't find it click browse, go to *C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application* and select chrome.exe.